# Facebook Fan Page - is it possible to share post on Facebook fan page using share dialogue of Facebook-iOS-SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-page

I want to share something on Facebook users page,

Which I have done using Graph API call using: "manage_pages" and "{page-id}/feed" using page access_token as parameter via POST Method

is it possible to share post on Facebook fan page using share dialogue of Facebook-iOS-SDK ?

I have searched a lot but can't see any option which give me useful info for Facebook share dialogue

Any information regrading same task is most welcome...

Thanks in advance :)

Update:

I can see what Facebook App itself is providing like this:
In screenshot last two options are My Page Names:

1) Kiran Patel

2) My Library

So How can we provide this options programmatically?

[image: Screenshot: Facebook native share dialogue]

Comment: I have successfully posted on page using Feed Dialoge:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.1
: Using "to" and "from" parameters


but still finding the way how can I do with "Share Dialogue"
:(